# Newbie - trying to save a datagrid to pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruport

I'm using the gem datagrid to display some data.  I would like to use ruport to output the data to pdf.

I added this button to my controller.rb=

```
<%= button_to "PDF", {:controller => :admin_reports, :action => :worequest_pdf }%>
```

I have this route=

```
resources :admin_reports do
post :worequest_pdf, :on => :collection
```

end

And this in the admin_reports_controller.rb=

```
 def worequest_pdf
f = File.new("worequest.pdf", "w")
f.write Ruport::Data::Table(:column_names =>report.header, :data => report.rows).to_pdf
f.close
```

end

But, it doesn't work - any ideas?
I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `report' for #<AdminReportsController:0x007fc463566218>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What do you see in the server window (terminal).

Comment: I get: undefined local variable or method `report' for #<AdminReportsController:0x007fc463566218>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruport probably is not your best option. It has not been updated in more than a year. Thats a lifetime in the ruby world. You may want to look at http://ruby-statsample.rubyforge.org/reportbuilder/  or go to https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ to find something more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the error

```
undefined local variable or method `report'
```

Should you be using "@report" instead of "report"?